# User input to display certain values in a dictionary using python

Tags: python

Given user input, how would I be able to iterate through my dictionary and only print out the names of people whose dates fall between the start and end year of the user input?

```
start = input('Start year: ') 
end = input('End year: ')

alumni_dict = {'Joe Smith': 2018, 'Peter Parker': 2018, 'Bruce Wayne': 2019, 'Andy Jones': 2018, 'Charles McLean': 2013, 'Katie Johnston': 2021, 'Rebecca Wilson': 2018, 'Drew Matthews': 2019}
```

So say 2019 is the start year and 2021 is inputted as the end year, 'Bruce Wayne', 'Katie Johnston', and 'Drew Matthews' would print out in a list.

Comment: Have you attempted to write a solution? One way to iterate over your dictionary is a simple : `for key, value in alumni_dict.items() : ...`

Comment: `{name: year for name, year in alumni_dict.items() if 2019 <= year <= 2021}`

Answer (score 1):

```
within_dates = []
for name, date in alumni_dict.items():

   if start <= date <= end:
       within_dates.append(name)
```

or in list comprehension

`within_dates = [name for name, date in alumni_dict.items() if start <= date <= end]`

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension

```
start = 2019
end = 2021

alumni_dict = {'Joe Smith': 2018, 'Peter Parker': 2018, 'Bruce Wayne': 2019, 'Andy Jones': 2018, 'Charles McLean': 2013, 'Katie Johnston': 2021, 'Rebecca Wilson': 2018, 'Drew Matthews': 2019}

print([n for n, y in alumni_dict.items() if y >= start and y <= end])
```

Output:

```
['Katie Johnston', 'Bruce Wayne', 'Drew Matthews']
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```py
def print_in_range(alumni, start_year, end_year):
    for k, v in alumni.items():
        if v >= start_year and v<= end_year:
            print(k)
```

Here's the output.

```sh
>>> alumni = {'Joe': 2013, 'Hank': 2007, 'Martin': 2021}
>>> print_in_range(alumni, 2013, 2021)
Joe 2013
Martin 2021
```